# Link button to html file in my resources

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have in `resources/static`: 
`index.html`, `app.js`, `login/login.html`, `login/login.js`. In `index.html` I would like to have a button and when you click on it, you go to `login/login.html`. I would like to do it in pure Javascript. What's the easiest way to do it?

Comment: redirect like just visits url? or changes view to this file without reloading documnet?

Comment: Why don't use just `<a>` tag?

Comment: Use `window.location` to change the location wrap it in `document.getElementById('your_button_id').addEventListener('click,method here)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'standard' way doing it without js

```
<a href="login/login.html">click me to get redirected to login</a>
```

'js way' of doing it:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="redirectToLogin();">Press me to get into login page</button>
```

javascript:

```
function redirectToLogin(){
    window.location.href = "login/login.html";
}
```

or jQuery way:

HTML:

```
<button id="loginbutton">Press me to get into login page</button>
```

javascript:

```
$('#loginbutton').on('click', function(){
    window.location.href = "login/login.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a button like this in html.

```
<button id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button" >GO to Login Page</button>
```

And use `onclick` action in button using javascript.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
                location.href = "login/login.html";
            };
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button onclick="goToLogin();" >click here to go on login </button>
```

javascript:

```
function goToLogin(){
     location.assign("login/login.html"); 
}
```

Note: Please check this test and decide the better one:
      https://jsperf.com/location-href-vs-location-assign/14